# PYinstaller doesn't convert working python code into working exe

Tags: python, sql-server, scheduled-tasks, pyinstaller, converters

I'm trying to get a code scheduled in windows:

```
 import requests
 from datetime import date
 import pandas as pd
 import sqlalchemy
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine

 server= 'xxxxx'
 database='xxxxx'
 driver_sql= 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
 database_con= f'mssql://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver_sql}'
    
 engine= sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_con)
 connection = engine.connect()   

 adr='https://api.swaggystocks.com/wsb/sentiment/ticker'
 r = requests.get(adr)
 json = r.json()
 pdbasses= pd.DataFrame(json["data"])
 pdbasses["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime("today")
 pdbasses["timestamp"] = pdbasses["timestamp"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 pdbasses.to_sql("swaggy", connection, if_exists='append',index=False)
 direct =r'D:\SQL\getdatafromhere\file'+str(date.today())+".csv"
 pdbasses.to_csv(direct, index=False)
```

the problem is, when I put it through pyinstaller it says I'm missing packages that I can't even install via pip MySQLdb,Psycob2 etc.
Then when the exe file gets put out, I run it and it just blips for a second and doesn't do anything. The code works in PyCharm. I tried running pyinstaller through pycharm, but I get a Linux exe file/spec file. I tried converting that one to an exe file, but still doens't work.

Thank you for your time

Comment: "it just blips for a second and doesn't do anything" --  have you tried to run the program in the command prompt to see if there's any error?

Comment: Hey, yes: C:\Users\breit\Desktop\dist>swaggyget.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "swaggyget.py", line 11, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[15096] Failed to execute script swaggyget. Pandas is installed though, once via anaconda and once via pycharm. Doublechecked and installed pandas on command still getting the same error

Comment: You'll need to make sure Pyinstaller picks up Pandas and bundles it into your Exe.

Comment: how do I do this? Are there settings I can choose? pyinstaller runs auto